# mod_rewrite screwing with php include?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm writing a basic little CMS and use RewriteRules to redirect each request to index.php wich then parses the rest of the URI and requires/includes different php files to put together the requested site.
The Rewriting and the parsing of the URI seem to work just fine, however when I try to include a php file all the output of index.php is erased and ONLY the output of the included php file is shown.

I wrote a basic script to test the problem but I can't find the problem:

The index.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['parameter_1']))
        $get_parameter_1 = $_GET['parameter_1'];

    if(isset($get_parameter_1))
    {
        echo "You favourite colour is ";
        if($get_parameter_1 == "red")
        {
            include('red.php');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "obviously not red.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "
            Parameter not set.
        ";
    }
?>
```

The red.php

```
<?php
    echo "red";
?>
```

The .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /htaccess_testing/

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [L]
RewriteRule \.(php)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^\.]+[^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/htaccess_testing/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /htaccess_testing/index.php?parameter_1=$1 [L]
```

When I request www.example.com/htaccess_testing/ it correctly shows "Parameter not set."

When I request www.example.com/htaccess_texting/blue/ it correctly shows "Your favourite colour is obviously not red."

When I request www.example.com/htaccess_testing/red/ it only shows "red." instead of "your favourite colours is red." wich is what it should do...

Can anybody point out my mistake?
Thank you
/K

Comment: I am not seeing any of the files content in your post.

Comment: `mod_rewrite` has **nothing** to do with includes

Comment: aldo: I accidently sent the form before posting the complete content, sorry.

Comment: zerkms: I do not know what causes this behaviour. I only suspect it to be caused by my htaccess file in some way. Finding the cause of the behaviour is why I'm posting my question here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you have specified the condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

It means: don't rewrite if file exists. Just remove it

**UPD**:

You need to put

```
Options -MultiViews
```

in the beginning of your `.htaccess`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't help. www.example.com/htaccess_testing/red/ still only displays the output of red.php, not the combined output of index.php + included red.php

Comment: @Kodekan: I copy-pasted your files as-is without modifications and for `http://localhost/htaccess_testing/red/` I get `You favourite colour is red`

Comment: Thank you the Options -MultiViews did the trick. (I just wish I knew WHY it does :))

Comment: @Kodekan: the `+MultiViews` option requires the apache to guess the extension of the file. And as long as file exists - apache run it, regardless of mod_rewrite rules